# Changing values to NaN pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a IMDB data frame that looks like that : 
[IMDB data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX8Oq.png)

I want to change all ratings and metascore with below 100,000 votes to `NaN`.
Here is my attempt :

```
df[(df['votes']<100000)].loc[:, ['rating', 'metascore']] = np.nan
```

I'll be happy to get some help here. Thanks!!

Comment: What result you get with your code. ?

Comment: You don't need to index twice: `df.loc[df['votes'] < 100_000, ['rating', 'metascore']] = np.nan`

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems OK. You might check though if you have missing values in columns `votes`, `metascore` and `ratings`. I see all these columns are `float`. If you have mising values in `votes` you might have a problem so you should try to make :

```
df['votes'] = df['votes'].fillna(0.0)
```